# How can I iterate through a model then iterate again in my view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to pull data for each of my users. I grab their `person_id` from my user table, then use each person's ID to figure out how many days each person has available, and show that in my view.
I'm not sure if I am doing this correctly because I am iterating in my controller then again in my view.

```
def how_many_days_users_have

 @my_group = User.all.pluck(:person_id)
 @my_group.each do |v|

   @indirect_id_v = Empaccrl.where("person_id = ? and is_active = ?", '#{v]', 'Y').pluck(:a_code).first
   @v_range = Empaccrl.where("person_id = ? and is_active = ?", '#{v]', 'Y').pluck(:ac).first
   @v_range_taken = Empaccrl.where("person_id = ? and is_active = ?", '#{v]', 'Y').pluck(:taken).first
   @total_v_hours = @v_range.to_d - @v_range_taken.to_d
   @total_v_days = @total_v_hours / 8

 end
```

Then in my view I use this to show me this data:

```
  %tr.trace-table
  -@indirect_id_v.each do |idd|
    %tr.trace-table
      %td.trace-table{:style => 'border: solid black;'}= idd



  -@total_v_days.each do |days|
    %tr.trace-table
      %td.trace-table{:style => 'border: solid black;'}= days
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, first things first, move some of that junk to your model, like so:

```
class Empaccrl < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.all_people
    where(person_id: User.all.pluck(:person_id))
  end

  def self.active_people
    all_people.where(is_active: 'Y')
  end

  def self.active_vacation_data
    active_people.select(:person_id, :ac, :taken)
  end 

  def total_v_hours
    ac.to_d - taken.to_d
  end

  def total_v_days
    total_v_hours / 8
  end
end
```

Then you can use:

```
peoples_vacation_information = Empaccrl.active_vacation_data.all 
peoples_vacation_information.map do |person| 
  p "person #{person.person_id} has #{person.total_v_days} vacation days"
end
```

Honestly, you don't even need all that, but I'm not sure why you are doing what you are doing, so I figured better be safe and add stuff.  Whatever you don't need, just ignore.